# Python: 'ModuleNotFoundError' when trying to import module in google colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colab python 3, when import from python.aux.plot import choose_proj_from_xar i got error ModuleNotFoundError

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr

from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML

from python.aux.plot import choose_proj_from_xar
from python.aux.ml_flood_config import path_to_data
from python.aux.plot import Map

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-e570b5b49079> in <module>()
      from IPython.display import HTML
      
--->  from python.aux.plot import choose_proj_from_xar
      from python.aux.ml_flood_config import path_to_data
      from python.aux.plot import Map

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python'
```

how to resolve this issue ? Thanks!

Comment: where did you get the `python.aux.plot` from? there is no package named `python.aux.plot`. Maybe you got this code from a project?

Comment: this is dependencies for project

Comment: this is dependencies for project: channels:- conda-forge - defaults || dependencies: cartopy, cdsapi, dask, dask-glm, dask-ml,gdal, geopandas, geos, geotiff, h5py, hdf4, hdf5, ipykernel, ipython, ipython_genutils, joblib, jupyter_client, jupyter_core, keras, keras-applications, keras-preprocessing, matplotlib, netcdf4, numba, numpy,pandas,pip, pyproj, py-xgboost, rasterio,scikitlearn,scipy,seaborn,setuptools,shapely,sip,six,snuggs,sortedcontainers,sqlite,statsmodels,tblib,tensorboard,tensorflow,termcolor,tk,toolz,tornado,tqdm,traitlets,urllib3,wcwidth,werkzeug,wheel,xarray,yaml.Any suggestion?